# Некорректная работа bash при вызове из crontab

Tags: bash, centos, ispmanager

Узнаю pid нужного мне процесса:

```
ps x | grep путь | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Присваиваю его переменной **TEST**, допустим, и тут же вывожу на экран:

```
TEST=$(ps x | grep /usr/share/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19/ | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ; echo $TEST
```

При вызове напрямую из консоли все работает как часы, можно запускать хоть сто раз. 
Поместил в crontab следующее:

```
*/10 * * * *    cd какой-то/путь ; sh myscript.sh
```

Скрипт, как и должен, запускается каждые десять минут. Однако есть некоторая проблема. Ниже привожу код скрипта:

```
TEST=$(ps x | grep путь | grep -v grep | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
if [ "$TEST" == "" ]
then
  echo "no pid"
else
  echo "pid "$TEST
fi
```

Скрипт прост до невозможности. Запускаю сам через консоль `sh myscript.sh` сколько угодно раз - все работает корректно. Запускается же он планировщиком - в $TEST записывается не пойми что, как я понял, значения суммируются (???). В ISP Manager зашел в планировщик, увидел что мое "задание" там тоже видно, запустил его - увидел этот результат: PID при каждом запуске задания планировщика другой, почему-то, хотя искомого процесса и нет вовсе.

Что это такое и как с этим бороться?(

---

UPDATE: увеличил частоту запросов до раза в минуту, добавил `echo $TEST >/tmp/debug-output.$$` и в директории tmp стали появляться такие файлы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В тексте файлов также 5значные числа, начинающиеся с 18. Также в теле скрипта добавил к grep и т.д. абсолютные пути.

Comment: А как cron парсит строку `*/10 * * * *    cd какой-то/путь ; sh myscript.sh`? Если он разделяет по последовательностям пробельных символов, то черти-че получится.

Comment: А как крон найдёт grep? Он у вас без пути.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, может, вот это что-то релевантное: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, тогда, может быть, дело в том, что cron выполняет это под другим юзером.

Comment: cron запускается с пустым (или почти) окружением. Сравнивать - в консоли всё работает, а в кроне нет, бассмысленно.

Comment: Добавьте  **конкретные** данные. Текст скрипта и вывод `есho $TEST >/tmp/debug-output.$$`

Comment: Прямо вот `путь` в теле скрипта написано? И все же, вывод значения TEST в отладочный файл приведите.

Comment: Хотите сказать, что в отладочном файле несколько PID-ов и они не то, что вы ожидаете? Положите в другой отладочный файл вывод `ps -x | grep /usr/dir/dir/ и т.д.` и посмотрите что там. Подумайте, PID какой из строк вы хотите извлечь и отлаживайте. Кстати, у меня PID для вашего примера извлекается (даже в консоли (правда у меня Ubuntu) через `cut -d ' ' -f 2` (а не -f 1)

Comment: Не видя всего, трудно отлаживать. Посмотрите все же вывод `ps -x | grep ...` Пишите больше всего в отладочные файлы и анализируйте.

Comment: А что до `| cut` не догадались посмотреть?

Comment: Используйте `pgrep` вместо вашего огорода из палок и костылей.

Comment: подозреваю, что ваш скрипт находится в том же каталоге `/usr/share/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19`, и в том числе и его *pid* вы и наблюдаете в результатах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

чтобы не приходилось «бороться» с результатами, выдаваемыми программой *ps*, много-много лет назад была написана программа [*pgrep*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep).

входит она обычно в пакет с названием *procps*, который по умолчанию может быть и не установлен в вашем дистрибутиве.

воспользовавшись этой программой, можно заменить все те громоздкие (и не очень-то однозначные) конструкции, которые вы используете, на лаконичное:

```
$ pgrep -f /usr/share/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19/
```

эта команда напечатает в *stdout* список идентификаторов процессов, в полных путях к исполняемым файлам которых присутствует строка `/usr/share/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M19/`.

учтите только, что, вообще-то, таких процессов может быть не только ноль или один, но и **более** одного. их идентификаторы будут выведены в отдельные строки.

да, кстати! если ваш скрипт тоже находится в этом каталоге (или глубже), то и идентификатор процесса, выполняющего ваш скрипт, **тоже** попадёт в список.